# Java: Save all tables of a database

Tags: java, sql, database, list

I have a project where I have a java object for the most important tables of my database but not for all. I have hardcoded a method which saves all rows (data) of only one table in a list:

```
private void migrateDataToMsSql() throws Exception {

    ObservableList<TSTRunLog> runLogs = TSTRepo.getInstance().retrieveRunLog(false);
    List<TSTRunLog> runLogList = runLogs.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

    Connection connMsSql = DBConnection.getConnectionToMsSql();
}
```

Now I want to find a dynamic way to save all rows of a table in a list and then make a list of these lists (a list for the tables). But I could not figure out a way to save them directly from the database in a list so that I don't have to create an object for every single table. I thought of using a SELECT query in general but didn't find a specific way how to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT *` plus calling on the ResultSet `getMetaData()` will get you the column count and column labels.

Comment: When you start talking about "all rows in a table" it makes me think you need to use a data export tool like `mysqldump` and not try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Architecturally speaking, when you need to store "a list of values" in a database, you ordinarily store one element per row, with some common value to link all of them together and to provide ordering so that a later `SELECT .. WHERE .. ORDER BY` will return the proper set of values, in order, one row at a time.  Furthermore, it is advisable to enclose all of this in an SQL `TRANSACTION`, committing the transaction only after all of the rows have been successfully inserted.  And, don't forget to check to see if records already exist which must first be `DELETE`d in the same transaction.

Comment: If you need to store "lists of lists" in this way, a common way to do it is to have a "list catalog" table with an auto-increment field which has a 1->Many relationship with your "list elements" table.  All of the inserts, to both tables, are performed in the same `TRANSACTION` so that "either everything happens, or nothing does."

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"Save all tables"`?